# Extending directives in AngularJS (sharing properties before and after link)

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which creates a rich text editor in its `LinkingFunction`. The small directive I'm using for my rich text editor can be found at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js.

I need to extend this directive with another directive which will allow me to configure the default options and access the element created by the previous directive.

If possible, I would like to do this without forking the original `ui-tinymce` directive (linked to above). In this directive there are two properties:

- `uiTinymceConfig` which I need to be able to access and configure before this directive's `LinkingFunction` is run (before the options are passed to TinyMCE)
- `tinyInstance` which I need to manipulate after it has been created by this directive

I've done plenty of research into [extending directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives), as well as the different attributes available to the ["Directive Definition Object"](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), such as `link`, `pre-link`, `post-link`, `compile`, and `controller`. I have experimented with sharing properties between two directives using some of these methods, but I have not come up with a solution that fits my needs (above).

I am happy to fork this original directive code if it is not possible to achieve what is needed without doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I investigated this a little for you, and came up with [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jqebiSSPQachr0VSWp5?p=preview).

This will let you override the value provided for injection - note that you can do this in a module that depends on the submodule, so you can provide different configurations for different modules that depend on the submodule, which would be of use for the ui-tinymce directive.

Using a similar principle, you should be able to edit the config value for uiTinymceConfig by just simply overriding it.  You can even do [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/dlQHbibKcpP3YbNv7rGC?p=preview) and override it right in the base module if you'd like.

If you want to edit the instance itself after instantiation, you can simply access it by using the ID attribute and calling `tinymce.get('#IDattribute')` directly anywhere in your code.

Comment: A quick note about accessing the instance after instantiation: I tried `tinymce.get(attrs.id)` in my second directive, but the trouble is that the `LinkingFunction` of my custom directive is called before the `ui-tinymce` directive sets the ID attribute.

Comment: I was simply chaining directives on my element, so, for example: `<textarea ui-tinymce ui-text-editor></textarea>`

Comment: This may not be the most desirable, but perhaps put an ID attribute on each element with the directive?  That way it will be fixed by you and not the directive - i.e. `<textarea id="myTextarea1" ui-tinymce>`

Comment: I think I can get away with just doing `tinymce.get(attrs.id)` in my second directive, as this runs after the original `ui-tinymce` directive. I'm not sure if that's just because of the order in which directives are defined — perhaps I should put a `priority` on my second directive in the directive definition object.

Comment: Actually, that won't work, as I have to wait for the `ui-tinymce` directive to run `tinyInstance.setContent` before I can get at the TinyMCE instance, and this happens in `$render`.